Verificar si puede entrar en turno y dia habil php mysql
hola solicitando de su amable apoyo y ayuda,
estoy tengo un registro de usuario con contraseña e indentity que es email o nombre de usuario.
pero tambien quiero verificar que este dentro del horario de su turno y dia para acceso a su cuenta, solo lo unico que no me queda es el constructor de login. entry_time es el horario entrada y departure_time es el horario salida.
les hago llegar el codigo que tengo.
function login($m = NULL) {
    $data = date('H:i');
    $entrada = $this->input->get('entry_time');
     $salida = $this->input->get('departure_time');

    if (!$m) { $m = $this->input->get('m'); }
      
    if($this->Settings->captcha) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', lang('captcha'), 'required|callback_captcha_check');
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
       
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');
        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember )) {

                              
         $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
         redirect($this->session->userdata('store_id') ? 'pos' : 'welcome');

               } else{

                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            sleep(2);
            redirect('login');
               }
            
                        
    } else {

        $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('error');
        $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message') ? $this->session->flashdata('message') : ($m ? lang($m) : '');



Cuesta entenderte en las dos preguntas que has hecho por ahora en este sitio, y así dificilmente se te puede ayudar. Tampoco explicas donde tienes el error y cual es realmente. ¿Cual es el problema? ¿Que te falta código por hacer?  Puez hazlo y si te da error nos lo explicas mejor y te ayudamos, pero tal como está la pregunta dudo que nadie se aventure a ayudarte pues no está claro lo que preguntas y quieres.

No se entiende lo que quieres, lee [ask] y el [tour]. No nos expliques con tecnicismos, explica de manera natural, como si fuéramos un random en la calle.

Escriba la pregunta con la gramática correcta. Al igual que el código, la puntuación puede dar lugar a errores.
